# How are database scenario based applications developed?

Tags: database, database-design, architecture, scenarios

You are building an application that uses a database. For example, it is a marketing/sales  software. The application allows user to create scenarios, one user may choose a different path to improve the company's sales, other user may choose another path. Each user's scenario is saved in the database, they can load their scenarios from database whenever they want and continue working on it.
The question is: how does the application alter the database? For example, there is a table "sales". User 1 has a scenario, and he has different values in "sales" table, and user 2 may have completely different values.
Would application create different copies of sales table for each scenario? Such as `sales_scenario_1` and `sales_sceneario_2`?
How are these kind of applications built?

Comment: I would never ever make changing the database model part of the normal application usage.

Comment: From the brief description, it does seem that you will need to throw a "scenario" id into your tables and queries.

Comment: Won't that make the tables too big? If there's 2000 rows for 1 scenario, then there would be 10000 rows for 5 scenarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a table with dynamic values:

```
sales
  ID,
  ...

sales_properties
  sales_FK,
  name,
  value
```

I would never change the database structure as part of normal application usage. You wouldn't be able to handle the different database models.

Comment: What do you mean with dynamic values? do you add an extra column to each table that holds user's or scenario's ID number?

Comment: You probably need a table that stores the scenarios and a list of property names that are available. The sales_properties holds the values. You probably need a scenario id on some tables. This is all application specific.